# how does fork() work if I want to create multiple children to the same parent?

Tags: c, fork, parent, child-process

I haven't really figured out yet how fork() actually works. I wonder how I can make a parent process with for example multiple children?

```
fork();
fork();
```

will this return a parent with two children? first fork() = parent + child, second fork() = idk?

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Answer (score 3):

`fork()` splits the *current* program, making two identical copies - the difference is *only* in the return code of the `fork()`.

So if you `fork()` twice:

```
 fork();
 fork();
```

Then what will happen is - the *first* fork will split `parent` into `parent + child`.

The *second* fork will split both, because the child carries on from the same point. Giving you:

```
parent 
+ - child
  + - child
+ - child
```

To avoid this, you need to check the return code of `fork()` and use the return code to decide if you're still in the `parent`. It's not necessarily a bad thing, but you need to be aware that it'll happen, and ensure you handle e.g. signals, return codes, waitpids etc. appropriately. So *normally* you'll do the `fork`ing from just the parent.

Answer (score 2):

It will make a total of 4 processes.

The main process will fork one with the first `fork();`

At the second `fork();`, both of the previous ones will create new processes which does make `2x2=4`.

Answer (score 2):

`fork()` returns a process id of a child process to the parent or zero to the child. So:

```
if( fork() != 0)  // create a child
{
    // we are in parent
    if( fork() != 0)  // create another child
    {
        // we are in parent
    }
    else
    {
        // we are in the 2nd child
    }
}
else
{
    // we are in the 1st child
}
```

You can also create a child process from a child process:

```
if( fork() != 0)  // create a child
{
    // we are in parent
}
else
{
    // we are in the child
    if( fork() != 0)  // create a grand-child
    {
        // we are in a first child
    }
    else
    {
        // we are in the grand-child
    }
}
```

To create 5 children:

```
// describe the work for 5 children
SomeWorkDescription tab[ 5 ];

int  childCnt;

for( childCnt = 0; childCnt < 5; childCnt ++ )
{
    if( fork() == 0 )
    {
        // we are in a child - take a description
        // of what should be done and go
        doSomeChildWork( tab[childCnt] );

        // it's the parent's loop, children do not iterate here
        break;
    }
    // else we are in a parent - continue forking
}
```

Comment: Gives a solution, but does not directly answer the question about the code the OP posted.

Comment: Yes, it does. The question was _'I wonder how I can make a parent process with for example multiple children?'_ The example shows how s/he can.